# Display emotion icon in Android TextView via Unicode chars or other way

Tags: java, android

I try to make a chat application for android. Here, I want to show emotion icon in android Text View.

I want to show Emotion Icon like this.

[image]

I found one project in github :: https://github.com/sharakova/EmojiTextView. Here is image in drawable but i do not use image. i want to use Unicode chars. So, How can show Emotion icon via Unicode chars.

Some one tell to use Spannable Text but it make my application slow. when use many Emotion icon in chat.

So, Here any way to show Emotion icon in android Text-view?.

Thanks.

Comment: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177. check this blog. uses image.

Comment: Why not going for Spannable text. Is it really hampering your performance?? As @Raghunandan suggested in comment Spanning is good....

Comment: Thanks, For Spanning Text, I need to search icon first from 100 icon then i make Spanning Text. it take time.

Comment: Hi @ Md Abdul Gafur . Can you help me ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25884503/click-on-listview-that-fill-from-a-epub?noredirect=1#comment40509319_25884503

Answer (score 3):

1) find UTF-8 character for your emotion
For example smile
http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/263a/index.htm

2) insert in to text value of "C/C++/Java source code" field
regarding to link above for smile it is "\u263A"

Answer (score 0):

You can use EmojiconTextView or EmojiconEditText from this library : https://github.com/rockerhieu/emojicon

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.